# ST_Contains returns false even when the point is inside polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to map a set of points to polygons if the polygons contain the points. However, there are some points that are not being mapped. One such point and the polygon are below in the code snippet.

Visually you can see the the point is inside the polygon, but the `ST_Contains` returns false.
I have tried other neighborhood points that are also inside the polygon, but ST_Contains returns false for them too; for example `ST_MakePoint(-84.58,39.230427), 4326)` and `ST_MakePoint(-84.585,39.2342), 4326)`

What am I doing wrong here?

My versions are: *PostgreSQL 14.6 PostGIS 3.2.3*

[image]

```
SELECT ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((-84.585328 39.227896,-84.5854 39.227091,-84.582297 39.226931,-84.579814 39.226704,-84.579734 39.227655,-84.581803 39.227805,-84.582808 39.227891,-84.583812 39.227947,-84.585328 39.227896),
                       (-84.57498 39.224684,-84.583235 39.225243,-84.588209 39.2258,-84.58831 39.22607,-84.589049 39.228048,-84.585328 39.227896,-84.585378 39.228675,-84.585625 39.228869,-84.585727 39.229359,-84.58622 39.229386,-84.589593 39.229498,-84.590133 39.230912,-84.591667 39.234951,-84.592398 39.236919,-84.590117 39.237578,-84.588891 39.238239,-84.587366 39.238404,-84.585377 39.238288,-84.585487 39.236062,-84.584519 39.235411,-84.583077 39.235276,-84.582059 39.2352,-84.582226 39.233943,-84.582934 39.23323,-84.582505 39.232916,-84.581202 39.232761,-84.580022 39.232693,-84.579739 39.235027,-84.579197 39.23499,-84.579081 39.235542,-84.579036 39.236059,-84.57609 39.236151,-84.575794 39.235809,-84.575727 39.235616,-84.576151 39.23535,-84.575969 39.232757,-84.575815 39.232113,-84.575047 39.231537,-84.574595 39.23146,-84.573568 39.231547,-84.573078 39.231422,-84.572944 39.231105,-84.572396 39.230759,-84.572396 39.230231,-84.572771 39.229587,-84.572915 39.228848,-84.572828 39.228272,-84.573789 39.227311,-84.573933 39.226985,-84.574451 39.225765,-84.573702 39.225247,-84.574423 39.225112,-84.57498 39.224684),
                       (-84.578585 39.232417,-84.5784 39.232265,-84.576963 39.232801,-84.576965 39.23288,-84.57725 39.233011,-84.578626 39.232514,-84.578585 39.232417),
                       (-84.577142 39.234675,-84.578928 39.234798,-84.578973 39.233758,-84.577438 39.233846,-84.577142 39.234675)))', 4326),
                   ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-84.589104,39.230427), 4326))
```

Edit: After using `ST_MakeValid()` on the polygon geometry, it works as intended!

Comment: Run `ST_IsValidReason` on the *Polygon* and you have your answer.